# App Store Update stuck

Tags: mac-appstore, software-update

I've downloaded the "Pro Video Formats 2.0.1" update at least twice, but it keeps showing up in the Mac App Store. How do I fix this?[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had something like with with another update a few weeks ago. It is probably caused by their database records being slightly out-of-sync.

I ignored it for a couple days, and it went away.

Comment: I also just snickered each time my Mac Pro tried to install that package. It went 5 rounds and seems to have sorted itself out. As far as I can tell, it's not a burning issue unless you really need one of the packages to work. I don't so I just ignored it. If you did need the update, then taking action might be a better choice than just laughing it off.

Answer (score 1):

I had that issue with the 2.0.1 update as well. What finally worked for me (see this [Apple Support Discussion](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7006966)) was downloading [Pacifist](http://www.charlessoft.com) and using it to install the update that I downloaded manually from the Apple Support site [here](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1396?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US). All you have to do is choose "Open Package" in Pacifist, select the Pro Video update disk image, and install the top-level item ("Contents of [dmg name].dmg").

This method seems to have worked for me. However, something about the installer seems to mess with file permissions, because Disk Utility had a lot to sort out after installing. This seems to have more to do with the Apple Installer itself, though, and not the method by which it is installed.

Answer (score 1):

From [Apple Support Communities](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7006966?start=15&tstart=0)

> Just called Apple support... here is the official fix.
>
> 1. Move all files from /Library/QuickTime/ to a temp older on desktop
> 2. Open AppStore and download/install update
> 3. Reboot
> 4. Copy any missing files from temp folder on desktop to /Library/QuickTime. For me this was 1 file, AppleMPEG2Codec.component.

Comment: Same one old codec was the same for me as well. I skipped the temp folder and just deleted everything. I used Time Machine to restore the one missing folder after the update/reboot.