# How can I get v6.3 Command Line Developer tools to install?

Tags: macos, command-line, mac-appstore, development

The App store is repeatedly wanting to update the same version of Command Line Tools (OS X 10.10) version 6.3. Is there a way to triage or diagnose this systematically? If not, does anyone know a [janky trick](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/182215/app-store-update-stuck) to allow the installer check for this package to complete successfully?

[image: mac app store - it's groundhog day again]

Comment: In the Finder, type `command + shift + g` and enter `~/Library/Application Support/App Store/` then press go. Open this plist, and expand the items till you find an entry for `Command Line Tools (OS X 10.10)`. Select the item number it's under (for me it was the last item in the list) and copy it, then paste it here. There may not be an entry for you, however.

Comment: Also search for Command Line Tools in "/Library/Receipts/InstallHistory.plist" and post it here. I will compare it to my entry.

Comment: Thanks @Froggard ! The former is a binary plist. The latter has two entries for the tools and they are identical except for the date key. The former has two entries as well. See http://i.stack.imgur.com/qRpXK.png

Comment: You could try downloading it manually from Apple's developer website. It's possible this will fix the issue, or you may see an error message during installation that the app store isn't showing. Worth a shot though!: http://adcdownload.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Command_Line_Tools_OS_X_10.10_for_Xcode_6.3.2/commandlinetoolsosx10.10forxcode6.3.2.dmg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In all cases, this somehow worked itself out after 36 hours or less for each Mac.

I'm stumped, but it appears something server side changed as opposed to needing a fix on the client side.